# dropdownlist doesn´t run in mode table (Kendo grid in angularjs)

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Need a demo or source when use a dropdownlist in mode table on filter column in kendo grid of jquery or angularjs.

```
             {
                field: "VolunteerConnectName",
                title: vm.module_resources.VolunteerConnect_Text,
                filterable: {
                    cell: {
                        template: function (args) {
                            args.element.kendoDropDownList({
                                dataSource: args.dataSource,
                                optionLabel: "Seleccione",
                                dataTextField: "VolunteerConnectName",
                                dataValueField: "VolunteerConnectName",
                                valuePrimitive: true
                            });
                        },
                        operator: "eq",
                        showOperators: false
                    },
                },
                width: "20%"
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

filterable and values for rows and values for mode table.

```
              {
                field: "VolunteerConnect",
                title: vm.module_resources.VolunteerConnect_Text,
                width: "20%",
                values: [
                    { text: "Sí", value: true },
                    { text: "No", value: false }
                ],
                template: function (dataItem) {
                    var content = "";
                    content = (dataItem.VolunteerConnect) ? "Sí" : "";
                    return content;
                },
                filterable: true
            }
```